# Inline a list with another element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a list inlined with another element, but have the element positioned far right, at the end of the container.

Something like this:

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap 3. But I'd prefer it if I could do it with CSS. I've also tried inlining it with inline, but the text sticks to the list and I have no clue how to move it away without touching the margins. Float left and right make the text climb to the top, which is not what I need.

Do you guys know what's the best way I could do this?

Here's the outline of my code:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <ul>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put everything in a container which includes the `UL` and `P` elements. `.someContainer` position would be set to `relative` and then assign `position:absolute` to the `p` element and assign `bottom` and `right` to 0.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.someContainer {position:relative;border:1px solid #ff0000;}
.someContainer p {right:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="someContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>List</li>
      <li>List</li>
      <li>List</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked. Thank you very much, cosmoonot!